# Cascading dropdown not updating sub-dropdown (Laravel livewire)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am building search filtering for my site and I am trying to use livewire to build the search component. The search component has a few filters and one of them is a categories dropdown with a subcategories dropdown below it. When a top-level category is selected it should update the subcategories dropdown with the sub-categories of the top-level category. This should happen dynamically without updating the rest of the component, but the actual search results should only be returned when the apply filter button is pressed.

[image: This is what it looks like]

But the subcategories dropdown is not being updated even though if I dd on $this->subcategories I can see the variable has actually been updated. What am I doing wrong here:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <aside id="tg-sidebar" class="tg-sidebar">
                <form wire:submit.prevent="submitSearch" class="tg-formtheme tg-formnerrowsearch">
                    <div class="tg-sidebartitle"><h2>Narrow Your Search:</h2></div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div id="tg-narrowsearchcollapse" class="tg-themecollapse tg-narrowsearchcollapse"  wire:ignore>
                            <div class="tg-collapsetitle">
                                <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-down">By Title/Keyword</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-themecollapsecontent">
                                <div class="form-group tg-inputwithicon">
                                    <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
                                    <input wire:model.defer="keyword" id="keyword" type="search" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Title/Keyword">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-collapsetitle">
                                <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-down">By Category</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-themecollapsecontent">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="tg-select">
                                        <select wire:model="category" id="category" name="category">
                                            <option disabled>Select Category</option>
                                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="tg-selectgroup">
                                        <select wire:model.defer="subcategory" id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
                                            <option disabled>Select Subcategory</option>
                                            @if(count($subcategories) > 0)
                                                @foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
                                                    <option value="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->name}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-collapsetitle">
                                <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-down">By Location</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-themecollapsecontent">
                                <div class="form-group tg-inputwithicon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i>
                                    <input wire:model.defer="city" id="city" type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Town/City">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group tg-inputwithicon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                    <input wire:model.defer="postcode"id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="tg-select">
                                        <select wire:model.defer="distance" id="radius" name="radius">
                                            <option>Distance</option>
                                            <option value="1">Within 1 mile</option>
                                            <option value="5">Within 5 miles</option>
                                            <option value="10">Within 10 miles</option>
                                            <option value="15">Within 15 miles</option>
                                            <option value="20">Within 20 miles</option>
                                            <option value="25">Within 25 miles</option>
                                            <option value="30">Within 30 miles</option>
                                            <option value="35">Within 35 miles</option>
                                            <option value="40">Within 40 miles</option>
                                            <option value="45">Within 45 miles</option>
                                            <option value="50">Within 50 miles</option>
                                            <option value="55">Within 55 miles</option>
                                            <option value="60">Within 60 miles</option>
                                            <option value="70">Within 70 miles</option>
                                            <option value="80">Within 80 miles</option>
                                            <option value="90">Within 90 miles</option>
                                            <option value="100">Within 100 miles</option>
                                            <option value="150">Within 150 miles</option>
                                            <option value="200">Within 200 miles</option>
                                            <option value="1200">Nationwide</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-collapsetitle">
                                <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-down">By Ads Type</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-themecollapsecontent">
                                <div class="tg-checkboxgroup">
                                    <span class="tg-checkbox">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="featured" type="checkbox" id="tg-featuredads" name="featured" value="1">
                                        <label for="tg-featuredads">
                                            <span>Featured Ads</span>
                                            <span>987327</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="tg-checkbox">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="urgent" type="checkbox" id="tg-urgentads" name="urgent" value="1">
                                            <label for="tg-urgentads">
                                                <span>Urgent Ads</span>
                                                <span>48952413</span>
                                            </label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="tg-checkbox">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="auction" type="checkbox" id="tg-auctionads" name="auction" value="1">
                                            <label for="tg-auctionads">
                                                <span>Auctions</span>
                                                <span>48952413</span>
                                            </label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="tg-checkbox">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="will_post" type="checkbox" id="tg-postageads" name="will_post" value="1">
                                            <label for="tg-postageads">
                                                <span>Willing to Post</span>
                                                <span>48952413</span>
                                            </label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="tg-btn">apply filter</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
            <div id="tg-content" class="tg-content">
                <div class="tg-contenthead">
                    <div class="tg-sortandview">
                        <div class="tg-sortby">
                            <strong>Sort by:</strong>
                            <div class="tg-select">
                                <select>
                                    <option value="Most Recent">Most Recent</option>
                                    <option value="Most Recent">Most Recent</option>
                                    <option value="Most Recent">Most Recent</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-views">
                            <strong>View As Grid</strong>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="tg-active"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i
                                                class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tg-applyedfilters">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Manchester</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>0 - 0</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Brand New</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Featured Ads</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Area Unit: Sq. ft.</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Sq. ft. 2500 - Sq. ft.5000</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>Rooms: 04</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>2014 - 2016</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="alert alert-dismissable fade in">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                                <span>1500 - 3000</span>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="tg-btncleall" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tg-ads">
                    <div class="row">
                        @if(empty($results))
                            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                                <strong>Sorry!</strong> No Adverts Found.
                            </div>
                        @else
                            @foreach($results as $result)
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 tg-verticaltop">
                                    <div class="tg-ad tg-verifiedad">
                                        <figure>
                                            <span class="tg-themetag tg-featuretag">featured</span>
                                            <a href="{{route('listing.view',  $result)}}">
                                                @if(isset($result->images->where('order', '=', 1)->first()->name))
                                                    <img src="{{asset ('storage/ad_images/thumbnails/'.$result->images->where('order', '=', 1)->first()->name)}}" title="{{$result->images->where('order', '=', 1)->first()->title}}" alt="{{$result->images->where('order', '=', 1)->first()->alt}}">
                                                @else
                                                @endif
                                            </a>
                                            <span class="tg-photocount">See {{$result->images->count()}} Photos</span>
                                        </figure>
                                        <div class="tg-adcontent">
                                            <ul class="tg-productcagegories">
                                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{$result->categories->last()->name}}</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="tg-adtitle">
                                                <h3><a href="{{route('listing.view',  $result)}}">{{$result->title}}</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <time datetime="2017-06-06">Last Updated: {{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($result->updated_at))->diffForHumans()}}</time>
                                            <div class="tg-adprice"><h4>£{{$result->price}}</h4></div>
                                            <address>
                                                @foreach (json_decode($result->user->addresses->where('id', '=', $result->user_address_id)) as $address)
                                                    {{$address->city.' '.$address->post_code}}
                                                @endforeach
                                            </address>
                                            <div class="tg-phonelike">
                                                <a class="tg-btnphone" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                    <i class="icon-phone-handset"></i>
                                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Show Phone No." data-last="{{$result->user->contacts->where('id', '=', $result->user_contact_id)->first()->mobile}}"><em>Show Phone No.</em></span>
                                                </a>
                                                <span class="tg-like tg-liked"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
              {{--  <nav class="tg-pagination">


  namespace App\Http\Livewire;
```

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Category;
use App\User;
use App\Advert;

class Listings extends Component
{
public $keyword;
public $categories = [];
public $category;
public $subcategories = [];
public $subcategory;
public $city;
public $postcode;
public $distance;
public $featured;
public $urgent;
public $auction;
public $will_post;
public $results;
public $model;

```
public function mount($model, $paginate = '10')
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->paginate = $paginate;
    $this->categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
    $this->subcategories =  Category::with('children')->where('parent_id', $this->categories->first()->id)->get();
}


public function submitSearch()
{


    $advert = new Advert();

    if($this->featured){
        $advert = $advert->where('mark_ad_featured', '1');
    }

    if($this->urgent){
        $advert = $advert->where('mark_ad_urgent', '1');
    }

    if($this->auction){
        $advert = $advert->where('is_auction', '1');
    }

    if($this->auction){
        $advert = $advert->where('is_auction', '1');
    }

    if($this->will_post){
        $advert = $advert->where('local_pickup', '0');
    }

    $advert = $advert->where('status', '1');

    $advert->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc');


    $this->results = $advert->get();
}


public function render()
{
    if(!empty($this->category)) {

        $this->subcategories =  Category::where('parent_id', $this->category)->get();
    }

    //dd($this->subcategories);

    return view('livewire.listings');
}
}
```

I have tried using the updated lifecycle hook for category property change but it still does not work:

```
  public function updatedCategory($value)
 {
      if($value) {
      $this->category = $value;
      $this->subcategories =  Category::where('parent_id', $this->category)->get();
 }
```

}

Comment: the whole code in the component blade is into a root div container??? any js code that could interfere??? any in dev tool? on category select change, you see any backend request in Network tab?

Comment: Yes its in a div container. No Js interfearing, only request is to the listings component and returns back the json from livewire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you change the wire:ignore in this line for wire:ignore.self or not use it if isn't necessary ??? i can't figure it out anything else in that code

```
<div id="tg-narrowsearchcollapse" class="tg-themecollapse tg-narrowsearchcollapse"  wire:ignore.self>
```

Comment: That actually works! Can you explain what was going on?  Also I have been thinking perhaps the parent-child dropdown would be better inside its own sub-component. Would that be a better approch?

Comment: Also, there is a problem that jquery that is used to open and collapse the filters no longer works when I change it to ignore.self. That is the wire ignore was there to prevent the js used in the original html theme from breaking

Comment: bootstrap jquery and livewire don't work well together in all the cases, so you have to handle that behavior. Try to manage the bootstrap js through Livewire, with the wire:click directive, dispatching event and in the scripts make the js stuff (eg. $('div').collapse('hide'))